# Regex: How to find a string, then get charactes on either side up to a dilimeter?

Tags: regex

I have a string like so:

`foobar_something_alt=\"Brownfields1.png#asset:919\" /><p>MSG participat`

And wish to find all oocurrences via  the substring `#asset:` then select the characters around the match up to the quote marks.

Trying to extract specific ALT tags from a SQL dump. Is this possible with a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `[^"]*` before and after the string you want to match. This will match any sequence of characters that aren't `"`.

```
[^"]*#asset:[^"]*
```